# the button of Jquery tab doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, tabs

i try the code from http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/form-wizard-using-tabs, but when i try this code, the button "save and continue" doesn't work. i try this code using framework codeigneter.

error on the console :

Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

the error was in here.`$(document).ready(function () {
    //Initialize tooltips
    $('.nav-tabs > li a[title]').tooltip();`

Comment: Error messages in the console? Can you create a [mcve] using the `<>` snippet editor?

Comment: it's just doesn't work, the button won't change or continue to the next tab.

Comment: @firm It does work for me

Comment: Check for console errors in browser buddy.. Press F12 if you are using chrome..

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at registration.js:1

Comment: @ILikeToMoveItMoveIt did you put more code?

Comment: No Sir. It just works as it is

Comment: @Firm this conversation is exactly why _you_ as the asker should suplly a complete and verifiable example.  Since you didn't do that, you can't verify whether you and the other folks are writing the same code.  So do it, and probably you'll figure out what's going on before you get done.  It's the easiest and best way.

Comment: @ILikeToMoveItMoveIt can i ask for your code?